# A bizarre phenomenon in the English language

Tags: wordplay, english

I've recently heard that: “Iambs are much more common in the English language than you might think — recent studies have shown that they appear over 100 times more than chickens, pigs and cows in literature.”

As baffling as it may sound, this is true. Can you explain this phenomenon?

Hint:

> Shakespeare

Comment: You're right: this *is* ***baaaaaaaaaaa***ffling.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is true that

> iambs

are much more common in the English language than chickens, pigs, and cows because

> iambs are a type of metrical foot used often in the English language

In fact,

> [iambic pentameters are natural to English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19634/is-it-true-that-iambic-pentameter-is-natural-to-english-if-so-why)

You are referring to this term because

> Although you capitalized the first letter of 'iambs' to make it look like an 'l', in actuality you used an 'i'

Hint:

> Shakespearean verses and poetry use iambic pentameters extensively.

Comment: Correct - nice one.

Comment: What about Shakespeare ?

Answer (score 10):

> Because they are writers called [Charles Lamb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Lamb) and [Mary Lamb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Lamb) (the Lambs), their name is on a lot of books.
>  I don't know any writer called chicken, pig or cow
>  Hint : They wrote [Tales from Shakespear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_Shakespeare)

Comment: No, sorry - not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @QuestionAsker ahah seriously !? What are the odds that 2 persons called Lamb wrote a book together with "Shakespeare" in the title ^^

Comment: @Lordofdark Quite high actually, seeing as they're siblings.

Comment: And...let me guess...after she gave birth, Mary had a little Lamb..? :-)

Answer (score 8):

Does it perhaps refer to

> iamb ( a metrical foot used in various types of poetry.) with a capital 'I'.